# Qual o problema com essa query?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, select

Certo, estou tentando fazer um select em um banco de dados por meio de ajax usando jQuery. Segue abaixo trechos do código que estou utilizando e maiores explicações:

**Função ajax**

```
function carregaRegistros(dia, mes, ano) {

    dia = parseInt(dia);
    mes = parseInt(mes);
    ano = parseInt(ano);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "PHP-Files/carregaRegistros.php",
        data: {dia: dia, mes: mes, ano: ano},
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Query**

```
// Cria conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Verifica conexão
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Erro de conexão: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$dia = $_POST["dia"];
$mes = $_POST["mes"];
$ano = $_POST["ano"];

$sql = "SELECT Cliente, TotalDeHoras, HoraDeEntrada, HoraDeSaida FROM 
apontamentos WHERE Dia='$dia' AND Mes='$mes' AND Ano='$ano'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Apontamento incluído com sucesso!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Já verifiquei e a conexão está sendo feita e os dados estão sendo passados corretamente, entretanto eu recebo uma mensagem de erro como retorno oque indica que o select não está sendo feito. Não entendo porque isso está acontecendo e sou meio novo nessa parte de criar conexões com bancos de dados. Caso eu tenha omitido alguma informação importante por favor peçam nos comentários

Comment: Qual o erro que esta sendo retornado?

Comment: Error: SELECT Cliente, TotalDeHoras, HoraDeEntrada, HoraDeSaida FROM apontamentos WHERE Dia='1' AND Mes='5' AND Ano='2018'<br>

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema não deixe de narcá-la como aceita, veja como em  https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

Uma query de select não irá retornar um true, como nesta comparação que está tentando fazer. Você pode até verificar se ela nao vai retornar erros, mas essa comparação que está fazendo ela nunca vai entrar no if. Por isso que seu erro não retorna nenhum error, porque não há erros... voce pode tentar fazer assim:

```
if ($conn->query($sql)) {}
```

Acredito que supra sua dúvida.

Comment: Obrigado, agora entendo oque estava ocorrendo, mas como eu posso obter o resultado dessa query? Pois o meu arquivo php estava retornando os meus echos, como posso faze-lo retornar o resultado da query?

Comment: Neste caso vc precisa fazer um fetch e montar o resultado num array ou numa string e passar ela.

Answer (score 1):

**O correto é verificar se há algum registro**

> O select count verifica o número de linhas não nulas dentro do `count` que você quer fazer!

```
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apontamentos WHERE Dia='$dia' AND Mes='$mes' AND Ano='$ano''");

  $row = $result->fetch_row();

  if ($row[0] > 0) {
      echo "Apontamento incluído com sucesso!";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
```

**ou**

```
$result = $conn->query("SUA QUERY")); 
if($result->num_rows){
   // echo "Apontamento incluído com sucesso!";
}else{
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

**Para retornar os registros**

```
$result = $conn->query("SUA QUERY")); 
if($result->num_rows){

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Cliente = $row["Cliente"];
        $TotalDeHoras = $row["TotalDeHoras"];
        $HoraDeEntrada = $row["HoraDeEntrada"];
        $HoraDeSaida = $row["HoraDeSaida"];

     }

   // echo "Apontamento incluído com sucesso!";
}else{
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas como eu posso obter todos os registros da minha tabela? Quando executei minha query só obtive o primeiro registro da tabela

Comment: @GuilhermeBartasson, resposta editada

Comment: @GuilhermeBartasson, como assim `todos`? A sua query tem uma clausula `WHERE` que só retorna registros que a satisfaçam

Comment: É que eu tenho mas de um registro com a mesma data (a condição que estou utilizando), mas já consegui percorrer os resultados da query e salvá-los em um array

Comment: @GuilhermeBartasson, o `while` vai retornar todos que satisfaçam a calusula `where`!

Comment: entendi, só mais uma coisa é possível passar um array como o result do ajax request?

Comment: json_encode($array)